# Using form onsubmit not firing javascript and instead reloads page

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I have the following javascript to get some information back that should be displayed on the page

```
function sendMessage(q,publicid,privateid,sessionid) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtAnswer").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "result.php?q=" + q +"&publicid="+publicid+"&privateid="+privateid+"&sessionid="+sessionid+"&donotdisplayheaderfooter=1", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
  }
```

The following javascript that I thought would prevent a submit from reloading the page and just perform the above javascript.

```
 function formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  
  const form = document.getElementById('theform');
  form.addEventListener('submit',formSubmit);
```

And the following form that just sends q to the form back to the page rather than performing the onsubmit.

```
<form id="theform" onsubmit="return sendMessage(document.getElementById("q").value,firstkey,secondkey,session);">
<input type="text" name="q" size="140">
<button type="submit" class="circularbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Where am I missing overriding the default behavior to just allow the javascript function `sendMessage()` to work on submit?

Comment: You generally need to do a [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event to keep the form from auto-submitting (which would cause the reload). This is easier to do with an event registered in JavaScript rather than using an attribute.

Comment: @David784 Would you be able to show an example using what I have above?  Is my function where I have the preventDefault() not functioning?

Comment: I am getting this error on the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" on the line form.addEventListener('submit',formSubmit);

Comment: Make sure the script is running after the HTML,  often scripts that are meant to interact with the DOM are put just before the closing body tag `.....<script>......</script></body>`

Comment: @Keith Putting that at the bottom fixed most of the problem.  Now I am only getting an error on ```<form id="theform" onsubmit="return sendMessage(document.getElementById("q").value,firstkey,secondkey,session)">``` saying that Unexpected End of Input

Comment: Even tried hard coding it with values and same error.  ```<form id="theform" onsubmit='return sendMessage(document.getElementById('q').value,"SVHRUWEHVIGHRH26589276","","e5c5e6dae38b284e8")'>```

Comment: I think I am making progress.  So it work if I take the ```document.getElementById('q').value``` out and replace with a value.  I see I named the textbox q but didn't give it an id.  I gave it an id of q but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that fixed all problems was to move finding q to the function and out of the form.

```
function sendMessage(publicid,privateid,sessionid) {
        var q = document.getElementById('q').value
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtAnswer").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "result.php?q=" + q +"&publicid="+publicid+"&privateid="+privateid+"&sessionid="+sessionid+"&donotdisplayheaderfooter=1", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
  }
```

Make sure the following javascript is in `<script>` tags at the bottom of the `<body>`

```
function formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  
  const form = document.getElementById('theform');
  form.addEventListener('submit',formSubmit);
```

Make sure the input had an id and my text was in quotes

```
<form id="theform" onsubmit='return sendMessage("firstkey","secondkey","session")'>
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" size="140">
<button type="submit" class="circularbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown for preventDefault should work fine.

Below is a working example.

```js
function formSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('default prevented?');
}
  
const form = document.
     getElementById('theform');
     
form.addEventListener('submit',formSubmit);
```

```html
<form id="theform">
  <button type="submit">Do It!!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this instead

```
 function formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendMessage(document.getElementById("q").value,firstkey,secondkey,session)
  }

  const form = document.getElementById('theform');
  form.addEventListener('submit',formSubmit);

<form id="theform">
<input type="text" name="q" size="140">
<button type="submit" class="circularbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `event.preventDefault()` is used; or in the submit attribute of `<form>`, return false is inserted

```
<form id="theform" onsubmit="return false"> <!-- The page does not reload -->
<input type="text" name="q" size="140">
<button type="submit" class="circularbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// Executes within the submit form event
document.getElementById('theform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Dropping the return false within the onsubmit attribute of the form, use this way (optional)
    sendMessage(document.getElementById('q').value, firstkey, sencondkey, session);
});

function sendMessage(q,publicid,privateid,sessionid) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtAnswer").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "result.php?q=" + q +"&publicid="+publicid+"&privateid="+privateid+"&sessionid="+sessionid+"&donotdisplayheaderfooter=1", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
}
```

I hope it helped you!